# how to replace url with hyper link that do not harm iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, url, iframe, replace

i want to replace url with links, the following code work fine but it will harm iframe (e.g. youtube), any advice?thx

```
$(".css___div p").html($(".css___div p").html().replace(/(\b(https?|ftp|file):\/\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|])/ig,"<a href='$1' target='_blank'>$1</a>"));
```

update:
actually i am doing a bbs, sometime ppl want to post a youtube, so they will make a iframe in the post... for example:

```
check out my mv!!!
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/F1C9zIA50Eo" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
http://youtu.be/F1C9zIA50Eo
```

i want to turn http://youtu.be/F1C9zIA50Eo into a link but not http://www.youtube.com/embed/F1C9zIA50Eo, any hints? thx

update2:
finally i did a stupid trick to avoid the code harm iframe:

```
var var___iframeSRC=$(".css___funk .css___div p iframe").attr("src");
$(".css___div p").html($(".css___div p").html().replace(/(\b(https?|ftp|file):\/\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|])/ig,"<a href='$1' target='_blank'>$1</a>"));
$(".css___funk .css___div p iframe").attr("src",var___iframeSRC);
```

update3:
i put all src to a array... but it still a stupid trick, any advice is welcome

```
arr___iframeSrc=new Array();
$(".css___funk .css___div p iframe").each(function(){
    arr___iframeSrc.push($(this).attr("src"));
});

$(".css___funk .css___div p").html($(".css___funk .css___div p").html().replace(/(\b(https?|ftp|file):\/\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|])/ig,"<a href='$1' target='_blank'>$1</a>"));

for(var i=0;i<arr___iframeSrc.length;i++){$(".css___funk .css___div p iframe").eq(i).attr("src",arr___iframeSrc[i]);}
```

Comment: Your update is not a proper solution. What would happen if somebody posts 2 (or more) different iframes?

Comment: yes... so, any advice... T.T"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you mean you don't want to change the links in frames?

if so, you need to add

```
if (window.top != window.self) {
    return;
}
```

to your script

### EDIT

ok. from your comment

> i want to turn [youtu.be/F1C9zIA50Eo](http://youtu.be/F1C9zIA50Eo) into a link but not
>   [youtube.com/embed/F1C9zIA50Eo](http://youtube.com/embed/F1C9zIA50Eo), any hint?

i believe this is what you're looking for:

```
function replaceURLWithHTMLLinks(text) {
   var exp = /(\b(https?|ftp|file):\/\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|])/ig;
   return text.replace(exp,"<a href='$1'>$1</a>"); 
}
```

source: [How to replace plain URLs with links?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37684/how-to-replace-plain-urls-with-links)

Comment: thx but no, actually i am doing a bbs, sometime ppl want to post a youtube, so they will make a iframe in the post... for example:
###
check out my mv!!!
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/F1C9zIA50Eo" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
http://youtu.be/F1C9zIA50Eo
###
i want to turn http://youtu.be/F1C9zIA50Eo into a link but not http://www.youtube.com/embed/F1C9zIA50Eo, any hint? thx

Comment: yes. its very difficult to understand your question. maybe you should start here: [ask]

Comment: Thank you, first of the first, sorry for my bad English, however, your code (and my code at the top) work fine, except a user embed a youtube video (a iframe).